# Add Column in Table with conditional in block WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I was doing a query with `MySQL` to save all objects returned, but I'd like identify these objects based in statements of the block `WHERE`, that is, if determined object to satisfy the specific characteristic I'd like create one column and in this column I assignment the value 0 or 1 in the row corresponding the object if it satisfy or not satisfy these characteristic.

This is my script:

```
SELECT 
    s.id, al.ID, al.j, al.k, al.r, gal.i
FROM 
    datas as al
WHERE
    AND s.id = al.ID 
    AND al.j between 1 and 1
    AND al.k BETWEEN 15 and 16
    AND al.r BETWEEN 67 and 72
```

The script above is working perfectly and I can to save all objects which it return.

So, I'd like to know if is there a way add in the query above, on block `WHERE`, the following statement,

```
( Flags & (dbo.environment('cool') +
dbo.environment('ok') -
dbo.environment('source')) ) = 25
and ((al_pp x al_pp1)-0.5/3=11
```

and determined the objects that satisfy or not these condition with 0 or 1 in a new column created in Table saved.

I read some tutorials about this and saw some attempts with `IF`, `CASE`, `ADD COLUMN` or `WHEN`, but none of these solved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has if function, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

So you can simply use it in your query:

```
SELECT IF(( Flags & (dbo.fPhotoFlags('SATURATED') +
dbo.fPhotoFlags('BRIGHT') +
dbo.fPhotoFlags('EDGE')) ) = 0
and petroRad_r < 18
and ((colc_u - colc_g) - (psfMag_u - psfMag_g)) < -0.4
, 1 --// VALUE IF TRUE
, 0 --// VALUE IF FALSE
) as conditional_column, ... rest of your query
```

Comment: I should put the `SELECT IF` within of the block `SELECT` or in the block `WHERE` ? 

thank you so much

Comment: Within the select clause

Comment: Thanks by your help